# Use a different icon for each instance of an OS X application

Tags: macos

Is there a way so that when I command-tab through the applications, each instance of Google Chrome will have a different logo?

I like having three instances of Google Chrome open, each with a different profile so that I can log into gmail with three different accounts (my personal account, my work account, and the Google analytics account of another site I admin now). So if there is a better way to have three different google account logins at the same time (so that each is in it's own space), then I may not have to care about changing the command-tab logo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I decided that I would rather have a different app running for each profile because that helps my brain switch modes easier. Furthermore, Google Analytics does not support Multiple-sign-in, which is what I need. So Google multiple-sign-in won't work for me.

@Kassym's answer seems to correctly replace the logo, but it doesn't retain the old logo as well.

---

so... I did something that may not work for everyone else, but solved my problem.

I copied `/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app` to `/Users/$USER/Application/CopyOfChrome.app` and then edited `/Users/$USER/Application/CopyOfChrome.app/Contents/Resources/app.icns` file to look different. (using [GraphicConverter](http://www.lemkesoft.com/content/188/graphicconverter.html)).

I then followed the instructions to [open Chrome with multiple profiles](http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?answer=179236), but editing the command to match my paths. I named the resulting app `SecondaryChromeProfile.app`.

What a freakin' hack ;P, but it works =D

Comment: Awesome, I've been trying to do this with Firefox. Looks like copying the whole app will have the desired effect. It might also have the pleasant side effect that my links are always sent to my default profile, no matter whether it's open or not. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Do a Get Info on Google Chrome and another file (whose icon you want to see instead of the default Chrome icon), select the icon in the top left copy it and paste it into the google chrome one :

[image]
As seen here I changed my Google Chrome icon. You have to restart GC for this to take effect in Dock and App Switcher.

Also in google you can turn on multiple logins, and be logged into all three accounts in the same browser :

[image]

Or you can get a program to do it for you : http://www.panic.com/candybar/

Answer (score 2):

A cleaner solution might be to use 'fluid app' it costs about $4
and it does a good job of giving you an isolated safari brower instance that will load a specfied web page with an isolated set of cookies etc.

works great for having multiple osx apps that are each pointing to some specific page.

Comment: Does it only work on Safari?

Comment: Yes it seems that fluid app is specifically tied to Safari.  There is a different app call 'rooSwitch'  this works on an arbitrary osx application (including other browsers).  but it works by swapping out the entire environment (on disk I think) for a given application.  This will allow you to have multiple configuarions, but I don't think it will let you run them at the same time.  alas you globally swapping them in and out.   (I still search on, for a robust solution for multiple independent browser windows  :-(   )